# Swap a list item with another using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to swap a list item with another using jQuery?

assume this list:

```
<ul>
    <li id="1"></li>
    <li id="2"></li>
    <li id="3"></li>
    <li id="4"></li>
    <li id="5"></li>
</ul>
```

How can change the place item 2 with item 4?

so that it

```
<ul>
    <li id="1"></li>
    <li id="4"></li>
    <li id="3"></li>
    <li id="2"></li>
    <li id="5"></li>
</ul>
```

is there any way without using absolute positioning ?

Comment: Be more specific on how you want this to be changed, on click, etc...?

Comment: assume, there is a <a> while I click on it, list item2 swap with list item4.

Comment: Change the place, or change the content?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#2').insertAfter($('#3'));
$('#4').insertAfter($('#1'));
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uHnNs/)**

Comment: This might not be the way JQUERY intend that to work but it is a really smart way to do it thumb up !

Comment: I would have assumed that the OP knew the ids of the two elements he wanted to swap, but not necessarily the ids of the sibling elements.

Comment: In order to swap first with 5th child for example, one would do: `$('#2').insertAfter($('#5'));
$('#5').insertAfter($('#1'));`

Answer (score 4):

```
var lis = $('ul li');
lis.eq(3).after(lis.eq(1)).end().eq(0).after(lis.eq(3));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Px6be/

and just for fun:

```
$.fn.swap = function(elem) {
    var elem = $(elem),
        before = elem.prev();

    this.after(elem);
    before.after(this);
};

$('#2').swap('#4');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Px6be/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the jQuery library called "Sortable". You can read about it and see a live demo here: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: Beat me to it. It's pretty versatile, and not only limited to lists. I've sorted divs and tables using it.